# How to judge whether my application for the NSF graduate research fellowship is competitive?

Tags: phd, funding

The rules have changed recently, and students can only apply for the fellowship once.  I've done some interesting research over the summer with my advisor and we got some interesting results, but I don't know how "small" or how "big" my research progress is for the fellowship application.  I don't feel that I have additional ongoing research ideas that can stretch out to a 2 or 3 year time scale, at least not without my advisor's input.  Basically, I still feel too inexperienced to have that kind of foresight, and I'm wondering whether that means I won't be able to send in a bona fide, competitive application.

I could, however, use my advisor's ideas for future work on our summer project, and those ideas would conceivably take a couple of years to work on and materialize.  But would that be stealing from my advisor, and me taking his ideas to another university / lab?

I haven't had this conversation with him yet, because I want to think about it a bit on my own first.